# django-password-strength "meter" not updating

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to implement a password strength "meter" using the django-password-strength library: https://github.com/noodlecake/nc-django-password-strength . The strength meter is able to render in the my `change_password.html` template, but doesn't update when I type something in the password field. Does anyone have any experience implementing this in their Django projects? Any help would be appreciated. Here is a link to my repo: https://github.com/brianweber2/project7_user_profile_with_django . Below are the main files of interests.

Thanks!

**forms.py**

```
class ValidatingPasswordChangeForm(PasswordChangeForm):
    """Form for changing user's password."""
    MIN_LENGTH = 14

    class Media:
        js = (
            'js/zxcvbn.js',
            'js/password-strength.js'
        )

    new_password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=PasswordStrengthInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'New password'}),
        label='New Password'
    )
    new_password2 = forms.CharField(
        widget=PasswordConfirmationInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm new password'},
            confirm_with='new_password1'
        ),
        label='Confirm Password'
    )
```

**change_password.html**

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% block title %}
    {{ block.super }} - Change Password
{% endblock %}

{% block header %}
    {{ form.media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="form-container" style="max-width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <h1>Change Password</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% bootstrap_form form %}
            <input type="submit" value="Change Password" class="button">
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```